# Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, pixel, gif, screen-capture

I have function that creates an animated gif, it always worked perfectly but now when all my gifs are black and white, it gives an OutOfMemory Exception On :

> e.AddFrame(Image.FromFile(imageFilePaths[i]));

My Function :

```
public void MakeGif(string sourcefolder, string destinationgif)
    {
        IsGifing = true;
        string path = MainForm.RootDirectory;
        String[] imageFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        String outputFilePath = MainForm.RootDirectory + @"\Final.gif";
        AnimatedGifEncoder e = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
        e.Start(outputFilePath);
        e.SetDelay(300);
        //-1:no repeat,0:always repeat

        e.SetRepeat(0);
        for (int i = 0, count = imageFilePaths.Length; i < count; i++)
            e.AddFrame(Image.FromFile(imageFilePaths[i]));
        e.Finish();
        IsGifing = false;
    }
```

AddFrame Function :

```
public bool AddFrame(Image im) 
    {
        if ((im == null) || !started) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        bool ok = true;
        try 
        {
            if (!sizeSet) 
            {
                // use first frame's size
                SetSize(im.Width, im.Height);
            }
            image = im;
            GetImagePixels(); // convert to correct format if necessary
            AnalyzePixels(); // build color table & map pixels
            if (firstFrame) 
            {
                WriteLSD(); // logical screen descriptior
                WritePalette(); // global color table
                if (repeat >= 0) 
                {
                    // use NS app extension to indicate reps
                    WriteNetscapeExt();
                }
            }
            WriteGraphicCtrlExt(); // write graphic control extension
            WriteImageDesc(); // image descriptor
            if (!firstFrame) 
            {
                WritePalette(); // local color table
            }
            WritePixels(); // encode and write pixel data
            firstFrame = false;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            ok = false;
        }

        return ok;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. NOTE : It's not because the black and white gifs, I was looking at the wrong folder and tried to add a .txt file >_>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) says that it will throw `OutOfMemoryException` if the file does not contain a valid image, or if the image is in a format that GDI+ doesn't support.

What happens if you rewrite your code to:

```
for (int i = 0, count = imageFilePaths.Length; i < count; i++)
{
    var img = Image.FromFile(imageFilePaths[i]);
    e.AddFrame(img);
}
```

If you get the exception on the call to `Image.FromFile`, it's because your image can't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find another way to load it. Say, how did you know that? you just checked all of my function for OOM exceptions or do you happen to know that problem?

Comment: @Or Betzalel: I didn't have to check all of your functions. You said it died in that line, so there were only two possibilities to start with. A basic rule of debugging is to break things down into the simplest possible steps, so the first thing I looked at was whether `Image.FromFile` could throw `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Oh, It never occurred to me that OutOfMemory Exception can be thrown by an unsupported file format. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but this doesn't look write. There are no 'usings' so you possibly aren't disposing of resources.